# Objective-C UILabel will not change color

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uicolor

The code I have is pretty much this (no custom views, just a single view application):

viewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
...
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusMessage;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
@synthesize statusMessage = _statusMessage;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
   ...
   ...
   ...
   self.statusMessage = [[UIlabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
   [self.statusMessage setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

I am able to change the background color and I have created other labels that display properly with which ever colors I choose for them, but no matter what I do this label always displays as a grayish color. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I don't see where you change your label color. You are just changing it's text color right now. self.statusmessage.backgroundcolor = [uicolor redcolor];

Comment: Is by any chance your label is highlighted? In this case, the `highlightedColor` would take over.

Comment: If the UILabel really is an IBOutlet, you shouldn't alloc+init it.

Comment: Thanks Anna, those were left over from playing around with interface builder. Totumus, the text color was not being changed with that code, turns out I had statusMessage.enabled = NO. Thank you @dasblinkenlight, it wasn't but I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is your label disabled? Check the value of `enabled`; if it's `NO`, that could override your color. Ditto for `highlighted`; if it's `YES`, it will use the highlighted color.

Comment: That was it! I had no idea that disabled would do that. I think it was just a copy/paste issue that left that there. Thank you.